# Basic animation unusually slow in non-IE browsers

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

**Test page:** http://adamhaskell.net/misc/dialogtest.html
**Tested with:** Internet Explorer 9, Firefox 6, Chrome 14

The page contains a stripped-down version of a site I'm working on. It uses a custom `Alert` function (uppercase `A` to keep the standard `alert` available). Essentially it creates a mask element and the alert content element, then fades them in using the `opacity` style.

The animation runs on a `setInterval` with a time delay of 25ms, over a total of 16 frames. The theoretical animation time, therefore, is 400ms.

**Results:**

- Internet Explorer 9: 397-403ms
- Firefox 6: 440-460ms
- Chrome 12: 800-900ms

And that's just the stripped-down, minimal version of the page.

Am I doing something wrong, or is Chrome, the "Internet's fastest browser," the bringer of "the Web, now," actually that crap?

Comment: Your test page is giving me a `404 Not Found` response.

Comment: My Firefox and Chrome are measuring a pretty regular 600ish on the test. My guess is that it's due to a heavy strain on the opacity change for dynamic elements, rather than on single rendered elements. It's not something that browsers are good at yet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "dynamic elements" compared to "rendered elements". It's just a couple of `<div>`s...

Comment: You're using `<div>`s with a number of properties attached to them, particularly CSS3 properties. I noticed the discrepancy when I was running the animation before any off-site resources were loaded. The CSS-less animation ran consistently at 400ms, but once it drew it with CSS, it spiked to the now-600+ms times.

Comment: Interesting. So it's likely the `border-radius` that's causing the problem? I'll try removing it to compare.

Comment: I would suggest removing all of the CSS3 properties (box-shadow as well), but I have a feeling that's mostly the issue.

Comment: You are indeed correct. I have made the same page without the `border-radius`, and suddenly we're down to 400ms. Well spotted.

Comment: Correction: It was actually the background image, more specifically the `background-size` property that was causing the slowdown. Interesting. Well either way, thank you for helping me find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'll just move this here, since this turned out to be the issue:

It's not the animation - the animation ran just fine when I had the external CSS disabled, but it's the browser struggling to render the CSS3 properties (namely `border-radius`, `background-size`, and `box-shadow` in this case) over such a short period of time. Removing these should cause much more normal times to match your expected times.

Tested on Firefox 6:

- Before CSS: 400ms average, consistent
- After CSS: 600ms+ average, varying

Tested on Chrome (no control test):

- After CSS: 500-700ms, varying

Comment: The answer was actually the background image being scaled up by the `background-size: 100% 100%;`. But I'll accept the answer because you did help me find the issue.

Comment: For the benefit of any others who read this, I solved the problem further by using delta timing, so the animation time will always be 400ms (give or take a little for the last frame). The smoothness, however, will vary.